# OpenGL: gl.h,glut and glew

Tags: opengl, glut, glew

I want to know whether or not, one can combine older gl.h and glew(for opengl 3.2) functions.I want to use the glFramebufferTexture2D,but my program right now can't find it since it only include glut and gl.h.What should I do? I don't want to use any shader programming at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix and matching header files is not a problem, because ultimately headers are just dictionaries of available symbols, *used only for the compilation of the `.c` or `.c{c,pp,xx}` file currently processed by the compiler*.

The real trouble starts upon link time. And with OpenGL at runtime, depending on which OpenGL version profile the context has been created with. In your case using a *compatibility profile* context would be advised. As long as the GL loader you're going to use doesn't clash with the rest of the program you're good to go.

> What should I do?

Get a GL loader of your liking (GLEW, gl_load, GLee) and use it.

> I don't want to use any shader programming at all.

FBOs are completely orthogonal to shader programming and the use of one has no influence on the other whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean when you say they are completely orthogonal to each other/?

Comment: @Mario13: "orthogonal" means, that the one thing has nothing to do with the other. Using a FBO does not require to use shaders. Using shaders does not require to use a FBO. (except if the fragment shader expects a output target configuration that can only be satisfied using a specific FBO configuration).